# Confusion over string-to-date conversion and UTC

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, datetime-format

When I do:

```
string strDate = "2013-03-03T22:58:43.0422158Z";
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Both dt1 and dt2 become `{3/3/2013 2:58:43 PM}`. I need them to be what the time is in the string, i.e. `3/3/2013 10:58:43 PM`.

Any idea how to parse it that way?

Comment: errm, that is what the time is in the string.

Comment: Really. I thought it's 10:58:43 PM?

Comment: Time zone issue -- you are GMT -8 (on the west coast)

Comment: Yeah, I understand it. What I'm asking is how to parse it without taking my time zone into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the equivalent time *in your time zone*.  If you want to store (or display) the time in Universal ("Zulu") time use

```
dt1.ToUniversalTime.ToString();
```

to do this when you parse the string, use [`DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89.aspx)

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, 
                                   "o", 
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                   DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

Comment: Well, I'll be doing a double conversion then. First from UTC to my time zone and then back to UTC. Is there any way to parse it without doing that?

Comment: It's not really a _conversion_.  It's storing one value.  The default display just shows the time in your time zone.  What are you doing with the time?

Comment: No. I get that value from a VS 2010 debugger for 'dt1' and 'dt2' variables. And to answer your question, I'm parsing a text file that contains dates in that format.

Comment: Right, the debugger is showing the time _in your time zone_.  Ad I asked what you _do_ with the value, not where you _get_ the value.

Comment: OK, sorry. Then the date is inserted into the database. And if I keep it as-is, it will be added in a local time (or converted.) As the debugger goes, it does not convert it into a local time.

Comment: You could take off the "Z" before you parse if you don't to use `ToUniversalTime`.

Comment: You nailed it, my friend. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it "won't take your relative time zone into account":

```
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate.TrimEnd(new char [] { 'Z' }), 
                                   "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff",
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                   DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```

[Other choices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89.aspx)

Comment: @DStanley - I've not tested it, but that is what the MSDN site says it will do.

Comment: No, this still returns 2PM instead of 10PM.

Comment: That's what I thought = the `"Z"` indicates Zulu time and trumps the `DateTimeStyle`

Comment: Well, I guess I can trim it out from the string. But I'd rather find a more "civilized" solution if possible?

Comment: @c00000fd - there that will fix the Z problem

Comment: Thanks, that would do it too, but it requires additional (unnecessary) steps.